# Mutt Hide Headers with Shortcut

Tags: mutt

I am trying to find a way to define a shortcut in Mutt to show the headers of the email in the Pager view.  IMHO the headers use too much space and I want to hide, apart from when I press a specific shortcut. Do you know whether it is possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

What's wrong with the `h` key in the pager?

That switches between full headers and "weeded" minimal headers.  The set of "minimal" headers can be defined in your `~/.muttrc` with `ignore` and `unignore` commands.  e.g. i have the following in my ~/.muttrc:

```
ignore *
unignore from date subject to cc
unignore x-mailer
unignore x-spam-status
unignore x-spam-report
```

BTW, `h` is the default binding for `display-toggle-weed`:

```
bind index     h   "display-toggle-weed"
bind pager     h   "display-toggle-weed"
bind attach    h   "display-toggle-weed"
bind compose   h   "display-toggle-weed"
```

`man muttrc` and search for `weed` for more info.

Comment: thank you, it works. It would be even better if we could configure what to display with when pressing "h" but I had a look in the man and could not find it.

Comment: That's what it does.  It's a toggle between displaying full headers and your preferred set of weeded headers.   By default, `mutt` displays only your weeded headers - press `h` to see full headers (and mutt will continue to display full headers for all messages into you press `h` again).

Comment: Brilliant - thanks you! :D

Comment: @MartinCastle not so much "brilliant" as "using a documented feature as it's intended to be used" :-)

Answer (score 2):

select the email and hit h. You will get bunch of informations.

Comment: What does this add to the [existing answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290327/117549)?